# Php Checkbox value as a image

Tags: php, checkbox

I am trying to make a checkbox show an image value.

I have a php script which process my  into tables in my MySQL Database. 
Instead of my Checkbox show "Yes" or "No" on the output, I want it to show a Green dot if "Yes" and Red dot if "No".

I think there is a pretty easy solution for that, but I'm still struggeling.

Any thoughts on this, out there?

Thanks!

Comment: This should help you : [Checkbox Images](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/vwphillips/ImageCheckBox/ImageCheckBox.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing "Yes" or "No", why not echo `"<img src='green.gif'>"` or `"<img src='red.gif'>"?`

Comment: This would seem to do the trick, but what I am doing right now is this:

Writing data into mysql database and the using JSON to pull it out from the database through a php process.

When in telling it to use a image instead, it just writes: "<img src="green.gif">"

Comment: That's what you want, surely - then when the browser parses the HTML and sees the img tag, it will request the image file, load it and display it as part of the page.  The value of the src attribute, btw, should point to an actual image file on your server.

Comment: I am actually trying to parse it to an iPhone Application made with Appcelerator Titanium and not a HTML page or through a browser :-) Thats where it gets hairy

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble posting the answer as the site thinks its an image :-)
i have added spaces to the php tag and removed the starting < of the img tag which are of course wrong, but at least i can post it

< ? =($checkboxvalue=='Yes') ? 'img src=green_dot.png>' : 'img src=red_dot.png>'; ? >

Comment: And what does your Input type look like?